# Unable to send tracking detail customer

Tags: shipment-tracking

When we send tracking detail customer then showing below error while click on (Submit Shipment)
request you to please check this and help for this.

*"Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity.**

Comment: please check you product quantity or salable quantity